# How do I specify a specific resource group I want to update in azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-resource-group

I am following the CLI from the [official azure doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-account-update).
Specifically, I am looking for a way to add a tag to a storage account in Azure through CLI. It looks like `az storage account update` allows me to do that.

But how do I specify the name of the storage group? Can anyone provide me with an example?

Comment: Are you trying to add a tag to a resource group or a storage account?

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the tag on the storage account and I have found it. `--name` is what I want.

Comment: Perfect! Can you please post your finding as an answer? It might be helpful to somebody else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error, I have found that below line worked for me:

`az storage account update --name storage_account_name --tags 'tag_name=tag_value'`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this:

`az resource update --set tags.'<tagName>'='<tagValue>' -g <your_rg> -n <your_sa> --resource-type "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"`

As seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources

Or this:

`az storage account update --name <your_sa> --resource- group <your_rg> --tags “<tagkey>= <tagvalue>”`